# OOB score and cross validation in python

Tags: python, regression, random-forest, cross-validation

Using SKLearn's RandomForestRegressor to build a random forest on a set (data)'s column 'sales', how do I find the out-of-bag error after fitting; And the cross-validation score in python? I'm trying

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

rlf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_samples=None, oob_score=False)

rlf.fit(data, data['sales'])

rlf.oob_score_(data, data['sales'])
```

but regressor doesn't have an out of bag score command

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you need, if you want a oob score (R^2), you can do:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
rlf = RandomForestRegressor(oob_score=True,random_state=11)

from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)
 
rlf.fit(X,y)
rlf.oob_score_

 0.8694467927166596
```

You have the oob prediction, if you want to calculate another score:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
mean_squared_error(y,rlf.oob_prediction_)
11.021243813623474
```

For cross validation you need `cross_validate`, this by default gives r2 :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
scores = cross_validate(rlf, X, y)
```

You can also do:

```
scores = cross_validate(rlf, X, y,scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
```